# Decrypt method throws undefined on Buffer node package with xxtea.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, xxtea

we have been using [xxtea-node](https://github.com/xxtea/xxtea-nodejs) npm package for encryption and decryption, as we can see the plugin is depended on Buffer node package, but during the decryption process, it throws Undefined error as below.

**Environment :**

**Node** : V14.17.3,

**NPM** : 6.14.13,

**Encryption plugin** : [xxtea-nodejs](https://github.com/xxtea/xxtea-nodejs)

**Decyption method which throwing error :**

```
function decrypt(data, key) {
    if (typeof data === 'string') data = new Buffer(data, 'base64'); //This line throws Undefined error
    if (typeof key === 'string') key = toBytes(key);
    if (data === undefined || data === null || data.length === 0) {
        return data;
    }
    return toUint8Array(decryptUint32Array(toUint32Array(data, false), toUint32Array(fixk(key), false)), true);
}
```

In the Decrypt method new Buffer line is throwing "ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined", but if I replace this line with the following line it works fine `require('buffer/').Buffer.from()`

Whats the difference between both and how to fix the first said issue?

Comment: did you run the nodejs code outside nodejs environment (e.g. browser)? did you use [tag:webpack]? its kinda difficult to work out an answer given the snippet is not a [mcve] - its an excerpt from the [xxtea library source](https://github.com/xxtea/xxtea-nodejs/blob/master/lib/xxtea.js#L304).

Comment: Yes, This is application is run on the browser. and we are not using webapack for bundling.

Comment: try slapping in [node-stdlib-browser](https://github.com/niksy/node-stdlib-browser), see if it polyfill your nodejs api. i'm not exactly encouraging running nodejs code on browser though..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and help.  Instead, I tried to add this in the polyfills and it seems to be working `(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).global.Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;`

Comment: not sure why did you use `xxtea-node` on browser though. i just found out a [pure js `xxtea` exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xxtea).